# How to make the next page from continuation of data when using repeater on wix?

Tags: velo

I have a website on wix with data connected to repeaters on the page. however my data is too big to show on the same page. How do I break the continuation and start it from the next page.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the number of items to show at once in the dataset settings. Then you can add buttons (and set the click action) or a pagination bar (and connect to the dataset) to page through the items or show more items.